# How to add a variable to ggplotly and place it on another y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add a variable to my plot. I would like it te be on a **separate y-axis.** Also I would like to be able to select colors of all the variables (commented part of code)
Any ideas would be much appreciated!

```
library(tidyr)
data = data.frame(Date = (seq(as.Date("2018-02-03"), as.Date("2019-05-05"), by = "days")),
                  var1 = runif(457),
                  var2 = runif(457)) %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer(-Date, names_to = "variable", values_to = "value")

data2 = data.frame(Date = (seq(as.Date("2018-02-03"), as.Date("2019-05-05"), by = "days")),
                  var3 = runif(457) * 100) %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer(-Date, names_to = "variable", values_to = "value")

library(ggplot2)
plot <- ggplot(data = data, 
       aes(x = Date, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = "stack") + 
    theme_minimal()
    # scale_fill_manual(values = c("#A90046", "#D1EAFE"), name = "")

plot <- plot +
    geom_line(aes(Date, value, colour = variable), data2) +
    theme_minimal() 
    # scale_color_manual(values = "#EDF2F4", name = "")

ggplotly(plot)
```

Comment: What do you exactly want on the second y-axis?

Comment: I would like to have another y axis on a left hand side of a graph. Var1, var2 values would correspond to the left hand-side axis, Var3 values would correspond to the right hand side axis. In this way all variables would be well-visible on the plot despite differences in levels.